# for loop, cell summation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, cell, octave

I'm trying to perform a summation. `omega` is a scaler and
`eigenVecs` are vectors, there are `i` (19) of them. I want to sum them into 1 vector. I want to store that sumations in `faceRecon{1}`, the next in `faceRecon{2}` and so on.

```
for i =1:N/PicDup;
  for j =1:k;
    faceRecon{i} += mtimes(omega{i,j},eigenVecs{i});
  end;
end;
%N/PicDup = 7; k = 35;
```

I get this error: `error: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 0x0, op2 is 11088x1);`

I kind of understand the error, I need to initialize `op1` a cell array that is `{1x7}` and inside each one of those cells in need to make them 11088x1.

How do I do this? Is this even possible? Is there a better cleaner way to do this?

Comment: First of all, `+=` is not a valid MATLAB operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your immediate issue, you need to initialize `faceRecon` such that each element contains an `11088 x 1` matrix of zeros prior to iterating through the loop.

```
faceRecon = repmat({zeros(size(eigenVecs{1}))}, size(eigenVecs));
```

Also, `+=` is not a MATLAB operator so you'll need to do something like the following instead

```
thing = thing + other_thing;
```

Rather than using cell arrays, I would convert `omega` and `eigenVecs` to actual numeric matrices and then you can use normal matrix multiplication to perform the multiplication and subsequent summation.

```
w = cell2mat(omega);            % M x N
eigenV = cat(2, eigenVecs{:});  % 11088 X M;

faceRecon = eigenV * w;         % 11088 x N
```

Comment: Thank you!  I apologize, maybe I fibbed I,m using Octave not Matlab. Matlab ~ Octave. += works in Octave. It's good to know += won't work when I use Matlab in school.

Comment: @user294448 In the future, if you're using Octave you should add the octave tag to your post since there are *very* important differences.